# How to print a key to the value entered by the user in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6 and I have to print the key to the value entered by the user. I'm given a long list of provinces and first letters associated with their postal code so that when the user enters a 6 letter postal code, the program will print the province in which that postal code resides.
*** I am NOT allowed to use if statements, loops or lists.***
This is what I have so far:

```
    data = {}

    # Initialize dictionary so that it maps from Province to correlated first letter         
    data = {"Alberta": "T",
            "British Columbia":"V",
            "Manitoba":"R",
            "New Brunswick": "E",
            "Newfoundland":"A",
            "Nova Scotia": "B",
            "Nunavut": "X",
            "Northwest Territories": "X",
            "Ontario": ["K,L,M,N,P"],
            "Prince Edward Island": "C",
            "Quebec":"[G,H,J]",
            "Saskatchewan":"S",
            "Yukon":"Y"}


    # Read a postal code from the user

    key = input("Enter a 6 character postal code (A1A1A1): ")

    #computer letters to uppercase
    key = key.upper()
    print("That postal code resides in", (data[key]))
```

However it gives me an error message with the print (data[key]) statement. I'm also struggling to figure out a way so that I can take the 6 values entered and print the province with no error as my provinces are correlated with one value. I just learned dictionaries and I'm having troubles solving this. ANY help would be great!! thanks so much.

Comment: The error message should tell you which key isn’t being found (right after “KeyError:”). Compare the key that it’s looking for with the keys in your dictionary (names of provinces – the things on the *left* of the `:`). Notice anything?

Comment: Your dictionary is backwards for the given task. Are you allowed to change it?

Comment: Dictionary is declared with "<key>":"<value>" order, so you'd better switch you dictionary to "T": "Alberta" and then you can do your task without if-statements and loops

Comment: Ok cool, yeah that makes sense! for some reason when I do this though it gives me this error message  "Y": "Yukon"}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  @yvs

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the comments and the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary is declared with `<key>:<value>` order, so you'd better switch you dictionary to "T": "Alberta" and then you can do your task without if-statements and loops
`data = {"T": "Alberta",
        "V":"British Columbia",
        "R":"Manitoba",
        "E":"New Brunswick",
        "A":"Newfoundland",
        "B":"Newfoundland",
        "X":["Nunavut","Northwest Territories"],
        "K":"Ontario",
        "L":"Ontario",
        "M":"Ontario",
        "N":"Ontario",
        "P":"Ontario",
        "N":"Ontario",
        "G":"Quebec",
        "H":"Quebec",
        "J":"Quebec",
        "S":"Saskatchewan",
        "Y":"Yukon"}`

Comment: Is there a way I would change it so that the user can enter 6 letters/numbers without getting an error message? The program asks them to enter 6 but I only need to take the first letter to output the province.

Comment: @SarD once you take the imput you can always take the first character from it. Something like `key = key[1]` once you have the input. Provided your keys are defined like suggested in this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
key = input("Enter a 6 character postal code (A1A1A1): ")
data = {"Alberta": "T",
        "British Columbia":"V",
        "Manitoba":"R",
        "New Brunswick": "E",
        "Newfoundland":"A",
        "Nova Scotia": "B",
        "Nunavut": "X",
        "Northwest Territories": "X",
        "Ontario": ["K,L,M,N,P"],
        "Prince Edward Island": "C",
        "Quebec":"[G,H,J]",
        "Saskatchewan":"S",
        "Yukon":"Y"}
options = list(filter(lambda x:x[-1].startswith(key.upper()) if not isinstance(x[-1], list) else x[-1][0] == key , data.items()))
options = "Code not found" if not options else list(options)[0][0]
```

Output for when `key = 'A'`:

```
'Newfoundland'
```